# Dynamic array with random numbers

Tags: c, arrays, random

I create Array with size N in cycle "for" and fill up random numbers.I have **startPoint** which means first size of array. **endPoint** it's end size, but **step** is step of size :)

```
for(int n = startPoint; n <= endPoint; n += step)
{
    int * Array = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);//Create dynamic array wit size n

    generationNumber(Array,n);// Function which generate random numbers and write to array

    printArray(Array,n);//Here I print array to cmd

    Executing(Array,n);//Here I execute some action with array, it's not important  

    free(Array);
}
```

So my problem is in results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP4HL.png)

It's a function **generationNumber**:

```
void generationNumber(int * Array, int n)
{
     srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
        Array[i] = rand()%1000;
     }
```

}

Why numbers are repeated? I feel that just add numbers to array.

Comment: Call `srand()` once from `main()`.  Don't call it every time you want a set of random values.  Resolution of `time()` is pretty poor, so calling it twice within (say) several seconds will give the same results each time.

Comment: `srand` should be called once at the beginning of your program.

Comment: ouuu, really, thanks a lot:)

Comment: Also you can use `srand(getpid())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`srand((unsigned)time(NULL));` will seed `rand()` with the current time in seconds. Running `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));` more than once in a second will reset its state.